# What is wrong with the way I pass this array in my mergesort?

Tags: c++, arrays, parameters, mergesort

I am getting segfaults when trying to do anything with the array that I pass. It's likely I'm doing some simple foolish mistake but I do not see it.

Merge call:

```
merge(&(array[size]), 0, size-1);
```

Merge

```
void merge(people* pe,int low,int high)
{   //cout<< pe[0].fname << endl;  
    if(low < high)
    {   int mid = (low+high)/2;
        merge(pe, low, mid);
        merge(pe, mid+1, high);
        mymerge(pe, low, mid, high);
    }
}
```

I entered that cout to see if I could access the array there, and I get a segfault there immediately. What am I doing wrong there? ( I can cout array[0].fname so there is no issue with the array of structs in itself)

Comment: How is your `array` defined?  Can you post it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've named your variables in the obvious way then (aside from congratulating you for doing that) `&(array[size])` is probably returning a pointer to 1 beyond the bounds of `array`.

Dereferencing that pointer will give you *undefined behaviour* as you don't own that memory,.

I think you mean to pass `&(array[0])`, or just `array`.